# Spring Data + MongoDB : adding multiple fields in Query only when passed field is not null or empty

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a Spring Boot project where I use MongoDB using SpringData and MongoRepository to store product details.

I have a rest controller which takes in the search filters such as `size,brand,style` and gives the response based on the passed filters.

How can I use multiple filters in the MongoDB query such that only the fields with values are added in the query. The fields which are null or empty should be ignored from the query.

For example, if my request is like below:

```
{
   "size":["L"],
   "style":["striped"]
   "brand":[] // brand is empty 
}
```

I have my MongoDB query like below:

```
db.products.find({size: {$in: ?0}, style: {$in: ?1 }}, brand: { $in: ?2})
```

which after substitution looks like :

```
db.products.find({size: {$in: ['L'] }, style: {$in: ['striped'] }}, brand: { $in: []}) // notice the brand has [] passed.
```

I expect the response to have all the products from all `brand` since `brand` is empty. However, it returns null since it also checks brand to be empty.

I would like the query to have brand only when brand is not null or empty ie. like below:

```
db.products.find({size: {$in: ['L'] }, style: {$in: ['striped'] }}) // since brand is empty or null, it is not added in the query.
```

How can I achieve this in Spring Data with MongoDB. ALso, I would like to handle this in DB side since I will be adding more filters and having them on the program side is not feasible.